# Rendering <html:radio> tag in struts

Tags: java, jsp, struts

I am using `<logic:iterate`> tag in my jsp page.

I am printing content in object using:

```
<logic:iterate name="rolesDetailsVO" id="role">
<bean:write name="role" property="roleName" />
```

Now I want to put this roleName in . Presently I am trying to do this using

```
<html:radio property="groupName" value='<bean:write name="role" property="roleName" />' />
```

but it seems to be wrong bcz in generated html the element is rendering as

```
<input type="radio" value="&lt;bean:write name=&quot;role&quot; property=& quot;roleName&quot; /&gt;" name="groupName">
```

Any advices please. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with

```
<html:radio property="groupName" value="${YourForm.property}" />
```